# When i open a generated PDF it results in a error using the new spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, google-drive-api

I brought the code down in the function below to the bare minimum and the file creation of the PDF is ok.
But if I use a file id created with the “new spreadsheet” setting on. The PDF opens with a error. If I switch back to the old version of the spreadsheets the file is actually ok.
Must be something wrong with the blob creation? Is this a know issue?
Thanks,

```
            function alone() {
            try { 
              var spreadSheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1lljK6wItraoMhI4NM3kueN69LZ3MSs-2mCWiM-W7tEU");    
             var pdf = spreadSheetFile.getAs('application/pdf'); 
            } catch (e) {
              Logger.log ("Catched something: "+e+"\n"+e.stack);
            }
             DriveApp.createFile(pdf);
            }
```

Comment: You say 'the PDF opens with an error' does that mean it does open? and what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

While there are [multiple issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=getas&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&cells=tiles) in the tracker regarding `getAs()`, none seem specific to the new Sheets. I suggest that you enter a new issue.

There are also [many known problems](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/sheets) with Apps Script support for the new Sheets offering. Again, no mention of `File.getAs()` there.